# Matching the values in the list between two data sets

Tags: r, dplyr, vlookup

I have two data sets that I am working. The first one is:

```
data_1 <- tribble(
  ~shop_name, ~sub_category,
  "A",        "Blu-ray, DVDs, CD",
  "B",        "Sneakers, Make-up, Blu-ray",         
  "C",        "Camera, Optic, DVDs",
  "D",        "Flower, Notebooks, Make-up", 
)
```

And the second one is:

```
data_2 <- tribble(
  ~sub_category, ~main_category,
  "Blu-ray",      "Electronic",
  "DVDs",         "Electronic",        
  "CD",           "Electronic",
  "Sneakers",     "Fashion",
  "Make-up",      "Fashion", 
  "Camera",       "Electronic",
  "Optic",        "Health", 
  "Flower",       "Home",
)
```

Now, I want to perform the left join to add the main category in data_1. The final data should look like this:

```
merged_data <- tribble(
  ~shop_name, ~sub_category,                 ~main_category,
  "A",        "Blu-ray, DVDs, CD",            "Electronic,  Electronic,  Electronic",
  "B",        "Sneakers, Make-up, Blu-ray",   "Fashion,  Fashion,  Electronic",      
  "C",        "Camera, Optic",                "Electronic, Health",
  "D",        "Flower",                       "Home"
)
```

And I coded as shown below:

```
data3 <- left_join(data_1, data_2, by = "sub_category")
```

But somehow, main_category returned the NA. Could someone help me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Below are two `data.table` solutions, for the record:

**Code**

You can either directly match each string in `subcategory` of `data_1` to its corresponding `main_category` in `data_2`:

```
require(data.table); setDT(data_1); setDT(data_2)

data_1[, main_category := sapply(sub_category, function(x){

  str = unlist(strsplit(x, ', '))
  match = as.numeric(sapply(str, function(x) data_2[, which(x == sub_category)]))
  data_2[match, paste(main_category, collapse = ', ')]

})]
```

Alternatively you transform `data_1` to long format and join with `data_2` on `sub_category`:

```
data_1 = data_1[, .(sub_category = unlist(strsplit(sub_category, ', '))), keyby = shop_name] # data_1 to long format
dt_final = merge(data_1, data_2, by = 'sub_category', all = T) # Join data_1 and data_2 on sub_category
dt_final = dt_final[, lapply(.SD, function(x) paste(x, collapse = ', ')), keyby = shop_name]
```

**Results**

```
> data_1
   shop_name               sub_category                      main_category
1:         A          Blu-ray, DVDs, CD Electronic, Electronic, Electronic
2:         B Sneakers, Make-up, Blu-ray       Fashion, Fashion, Electronic
3:         C        Camera, Optic, DVDs     Electronic, Health, Electronic
4:         D Flower, Notebooks, Make-up                  Home, NA, Fashion

> dt_final
   shop_name               sub_category                      main_category
1:         A          Blu-ray, CD, DVDs Electronic, Electronic, Electronic
2:         B Blu-ray, Make-up, Sneakers       Electronic, Fashion, Fashion
3:         C        Camera, DVDs, Optic     Electronic, Electronic, Health
4:         D Flower, Make-up, Notebooks                  Home, Fashion, NA
```

Answer (score 0):

You basically need to split the subcategory strings from `data_1` and then join, i.e.

```
data_1 %>% 
 separate_rows(sub_category, sep = ', ') %>% 
 left_join(data_2, by = 'sub_category') %>% 
 group_by(shop_name) %>% 
 summarise_all(funs(toString))
```

which gives,

> ```
> # A tibble: 4 x 3
>   shop_name sub_category               main_category                     
>   <chr>     <chr>                      <chr>                             
> 1 A         Blu-ray, DVDs, CD          Electronic, Electronic, Electronic
> 2 B         Sneakers, Make-up, Blu-ray Fashion, Fashion, Electronic      
> 3 C         Camera, Optic, DVDs        Electronic, Health, Electronic    
> 4 D         Flower, Notebooks, Make-up Home, NA, Fashion
> ```

If you have more columns, then `summarise_all` needs to be replaced with `summarise_at(vars(contains('category')), funs(toString))`

Comment: Thank you for your comment. There is only one problem regarding your code. I have different columns apart from these two categories. In this case,  summarise_all(funs(toString)) does not work well. Is there any way to "toString" to only two columns?

Comment: Edited my answer.Please have a look now. You can change the pattern in `contains()` to accomodate your case